# Fastcgi vs apache connect db

Tags: php, apache

I have php with connect to SQL Server.

```
<?php
$serverName = "AC-CLOUD"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DataSEAS", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Masterkey2010", "CharacterSet"  => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>

$sql = "SELECT sc.Id as Id, sc.Code, sc.Name, sc.Specification, sc.Specification2, sc.X_Specification3, f.Name as firma_Name FROM StoreCards sc
left join firms f on f.id = sc. X_pozicane_u ";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

When I connected it with fastcgi, it is working fine, but now I need to connect it with Apache and it isn't working with this code. When I tried another php code with Apache, or `phpinfo`, it's working fine, but this connect to db with apache, doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: In what way is it not working? What error are you getting? What is it doing that you don't want it to be?

Comment: only show blank page, how i can set to show errors on page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33665510/1064767

Comment: thanks, now displaying this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\connect.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php(15): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\connect.php on line 4

Comment: line 4 is $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() error means that sqlsrv module hasn't been loaded, you should edit your .ini file and add sqlsrv to the extensions

This pages shows the example of iis express but you can see how to load sqlsrv dll s in your .ini

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/windows/step/2.html

Comment: hello, thank you, you helped me, when i installed sqlsrv module, then working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

going by the information in the comments, your apache mod_php installation doesn't have the SQLSRV extension installed, but your php-fpm installation does. instructions on installing it can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.setup.php